# Create multiple directories with mode and loop via ansible

Tags: ansible-playbook

I'm trying to play with loop and ask in a playbook to ansible creating multiple directories on a server with specific attributes : mode owner group .

I think i'm close but don't get it working.

I get this error:

> Unsupported parameters for (file) module: recursive Supported parameters include: _diff_peek, _original_basename, access_time, access_time_format, attributes, backup, content, delimiter, directory_mode, follow, force, group, mode, modification_time, modification_time_format, owner, path, recurse, regexp, remote_src, selevel, serole, setype, seuser, src, state, unsafe_writes

Any advice would be very appreciated :

Here is the playbook sample :

```
  - name: ansible create directory with_items example
file:
  path: "{{ item.dest }}"
  mode: "{{item.mode}}"
  owner: "{{item.owner}}"
  group: "{{item.group}}"
  recursive: true   
  state: directory
loop:
  - { dest: '/var/lib/tftpboot/os/uefi/debian11', mode: '0744', owner: 'root', group: 'root' }
  - { dest: '/var/lib/tftpboot/os/uefi/ubuntu2004D', mode: '0744', owner: 'root', group: 'root'}
  - { dest: '/var/lib/tftpboot/os/uefi/f34w', mode: '0744', owner: 'root', group: 'root'}
  - { dest: '/var/lib/tftpboot/os/uefi/f34s', mode: '0744', owner: 'root', group: 'root'}
  - { dest: '/srv/nfs/isos', mode: '0744', owner: 'root', group: 'rpcuser'}
  - { dest: '/srv/nfs/pxe/debian11', mode: '0744', owner: 'root', group: 'rpcuser'}
  - { dest: '/srv/nfs/pxe/ubuntu2004', mode: '0744', owner: 'root', group: 'rpcuser'}
  - { dest: '/srv/nfs/pxe/f34w', mode: '0744', owner: 'root', group: 'rpcuser'}
  - { dest: '/srv/nfs/pxe/f34s', mode: '0744', owner: 'root', group: 'rpcuser'}
  - { dest: '/tmp/debian11', mode: '0744', owner: 'root', group: 'root'}
  - { dest: '/tmp/f34w', mode: '0744', owner: 'root', group: 'root'}
  - { dest: '/tmp/ubuntu2004D', mode: '0744', owner: 'root', group: 'root'}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo in the parameters. The parameter is called [`recurse`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html#parameter-recurse), you've written `recursive`.

Comment: Thank you. I really need some rest.